# User can successfully log in but log in page shows up instead of redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have a moved a project from asp.net mvc 2 to asp.net 4 and after a bit of fixing everything seemed to work.

EXCEPT for the parts of the app where you have to authorize. Without authorizing it is possible to view non-authorize pages but as soon as you try to log-in everything goes 
bananas. When you log-in you get logged in (you see your name in the log-in partial) but not redirected and prompted to log-in again and you can not reach parts of the 
app that is for non-authorized users. Everything works on localhost but not at deployed site.

- At first i thought there was a problem with my machinekey and app-pool recykling, so i added one. Still same problem.

I know that MVC uses websecurity instead of membership but i've read that an Membership solution can exist in a mvc 4 project, and i would be glad to use my custom membershipprovider and roleprovider and save some time if it is possible.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, true);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
                var role = userRepo.usersInRoles.First(x => x.userMail == model.UserName);
                if (role.roleName == "Business")
                    return RedirectToAction("Start", "Business");
                if (role.roleName == "Admin")
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Config settings for Membership & Role

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="AccountMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AccountMembershipProvider" type="MyApp.UI.Infrastructure.AccountMembershipProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="RoleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="RoleMembershipProvider" type="MyApp.UI.Infrastructure.RoleMembershipProvider" />
```